# Apache httpd not behaving properly when running docker image

Tags: apache, docker, httpd.conf

Environment :

```
- Docker version 1.6.2, build ba1f6c3/1.6.2
- Centos 7
- apache httpd 2.4.6
```

I have created the docker image of apache httpd. There is simple shell script inside that start the httpd server. 
My start-httpd.sh

```
httpd -k start
#to keep process running
tail -f /dev/null
```

Now the configuration i copy to docker image is similar to one I run on my main host machine.

Sample config of load balancer:

```
 <VirtualHost localhost:8000>
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ErrorLog logs/error_domain.log
    SetHandler balancer-manager

 <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
<Location /balancer-manager>
       SetHandler balancer-manager
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
</Location>
    <Proxy balancer://idp>
        BalancerMember http://punvm-core05.sigmasys.net:9091
        BalancerMember http://punvm-core06.sigmasys.net:8091 status=+H
        #ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    </Proxy>
   ProxyPass /homepage balancer://idp   
   ProxyPassReverse /homepage  balancer://idp
   ProxyPass /assets  balancer://idp/assets   
   ProxyPassReverse /assets  balancer://idp/assets
   ProxyPass /saml-idp   balancer://idp/saml-idp   
   ProxyPassReverse /saml-idp  balancer://idp/saml-idp
</VirtualHost>
```

Now this is how i run docker image,

```
docker run  -d -p 10000:8000 auth/loadbalancer /home/start-httpd.sh
```

I am able to access the http://localhost:10000 but the page i expect is different

Attaching snapshot of expected and unexpected httpd server page

Expected image , this is from my host machine:

[image]

Unexpected image when accessing apache mapped to port inside docker as mentioned in above command of docker

[image]

Also when i login to container and do curl command ,in response i can see Load balancer page but from outside the container i see response of unexpected image.

Please suggest why this is happening, am i missing something .

Comment: Thanks...I found from your question that I should add a "tail -f /dev/null" :) For some reason the -DFOREGROUND option in the Dockerfile of the apache repo wouldn't work for me.

Comment: yes this is how i keep my container running.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this.
i had to run command like this,

```
docker run  -d --net=host auth/loadbalancer /home/start-httpd.sh
```

So i don't need any port mapping here, all the translation internal container is done automatically when using this.